# Using ansible to create postgres user on aws vps ubuntu 22.04

Tags: postgresql, ansible, devops

I have a code like this:

```
- name: Create DB user
  postgresql_user:
    state: present
    name: "{{db_user}}"
    password: "{{db_pass}}"
  become: true
  become_user: postgres

- name: Create DB instance
  postgresql_db:
    state: present
    name: "{{db_name}}"
    owner: "{{db_user}}"
  become: true
  become_user: postgres
```

And got the error :

```
TASK [deploy/django-api/db : Create DB user] ***********************************
fatal: [aws-server]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chmod: invalid mode: 'A+user:postgres:rx:allow'\nTry 'chmod --help' for more information.\n}). For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-core/2.13/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}
```

By the way the installation of postgres is done successfully, also i test to create postgres user directly on the server and it's created, using the command

```
sudo -u postgres createuser --interactive
```

If anyone can help me with thanks.

**EDIT :** i fixed it by installing ACL on the remote server :

```
sudo apt-get install acl
```